# Do "sich etw. in den Kopf setzen" and "etw. im Kopf haben" always have a positive/negative connotation respectively?

Tags: connotation, french

In conversation with my friend, I said:

> Er mag zwar ein richtiger kleiner Unruhestifter gewesen sein und **hatte** vielleicht immer nur Unfug **im Kopf**, aber wenn er **sich** etwas **in den Kopf gesetzt** hatte, dann wollte er es auch unbedingt bis zum Ende durchziehen.

I get the impression that the expression "***etw. im Kopf haben***" often, if not always, has a pejorative connotation, used with a noun like "*Unfug*" in my phrasing, whereas the expression "***sich etw. in den Kopf setzen***" has a positive sense, often coupled with a noun like "*Ziel*".

But I'm not sure if I'm on the right track here, all the more because this would make for an interesting contrast to French where it works the other way around:

The expression "***se mettre en tête***" -- literally translating as "*sich etw. in den Kopf setzen*" -- almost always has a pejorative connotation  in French, while the expression "***avoir qch. en tête***" -- literally translating as "*etw. im Kopf haben*" -- per se is neutral and can take on a positive or negative meaning, depending on the noun used.

Answer (score 5):

No. It's the same as in French.

**Im Kopf haben** has no particular connotation.

> Ich habe immer noch den Geruch der See im Kopf.

It's the memory of the scent in my head.

> Du, Stefan hat echt nur noch Nina im Kopf.

Stefan is doted upon Nina.

> Sie hat immer so schräge Ideen im Kopf.

*Schräge Ideen* aren't bad but just *odd*.

What's important is the difference between ***im*** Kopf haben and ***am*** Kopf haben:

> Unser neuer Lehrling hat was im Kopf, das merkt man.

That apprentice is smart.

> Unsere Lehrlinge haben höchstens was am Kopf.

Those apprentices in contrary may have a mental illness, at most. If not, they are just dumb. Nobody knows.

---

In contrary **sich etw. in den Kopf setzen** has the connotation of stubbornness and ill ideas.

> Ihr wollt schon wieder umziehen? – Meine Frau hat es sich nun mal in den Kopf gesetzt, dass sie nach Berlin muss.

He doesn't want to go.

> Mein Mann hat es sich in den Kopf gesetzt, einen Sportwagen fahren zu müssen.

She thinks it's foolish.

Note the clause with *müssen*. That's not a real *must*, but rather an imagined one.

Comment: I see. I need to readjust my thinking on all those nuances. By the way, the way I used these two phrases in conversation... does it sound idiomatic enough?

Comment: It's excellent.

Comment: Den Geruch der See würde ich eher in der Nase haben - die anderen Beispiele sind OK